# How to retrieve values from a query in VBA and assign them as variables in Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to retrieve the values from an existing query and assign variable to it using VBA (Access 2016), to be able to use it in the further code.

And I'm totally stuck in that step, a very simple one, but I'm a newbie in VBA. 
I have a query, which in SQL looks like that:

```
SELECT Max(CatalogConditions.DefConditionID) AS MaxDefConditionID, Max(ImplantCondition.InteractionID) AS MaxImplantCondition_InterationID, Max(Results_Epilepsy_BSL.ResultEpilepsyBSL_ID) AS MaxBSLresultsID, Max(Results_Epilepsy_Post.ResultEpilepsyPost_ID) AS MaxPOSTresultsID
FROM ((CatalogConditions INNER JOIN ImplantCondition ON CatalogConditions.DefConditionID = ImplantCondition.DefConditionID) INNER JOIN Results_Epilepsy_BSL ON ImplantCondition.InteractionID = Results_Epilepsy_BSL.InteractionID) INNER JOIN Results_Epilepsy_Post ON ImplantCondition.InteractionID = Results_Epilepsy_Post.InteractionID;
```

So, I'd like to assign all these Max... IDs to variables in my code, which I'm going to use later.

If anyone could help me, it would be great. Thx

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-openrecordset-method-dao

Comment: Andre, I used the second option, "The following example shows how to open a Recordset based on a table or a query.", but still I have no clue where are the variables hidden in rsQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You open a recordset, and then read the values from its fields.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim DefConditionID As Long
Dim InteractionID As Long
' ...

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("myQuery")
' Read values into variables
DefConditionID = rst!MaxDefConditionID
InteractionID = rst!MaxImplantCondition_InterationID
' ...
rst.Close
```

Note that this reads the values from the first record of the query, so this assumes that the query only returns a single record.

To read one single value from a query or table, you can also use the [`DLookup` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed. My query returns only one record, so it's perfect.